# How to check authorization before changing redirection url in httpcontext?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using basic authentication using httpmodule. In that I need to change the System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation after authorization of user.

I tried using,

```
    context.EndRequest += OnApplicationEndRequest;
    context.AuthorizeRequest += OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
    context.PostAuthenticateRequest += context_BeginRequest;
```

In the above context is HttpContext coming from client.

`OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest` contains code for authorization and `context_BeginRequest` contains code for changing redirect location.

In my code, if context_BeginRequest is not there it authorizes the user, but if I enabled that it is not authorizing the context.